# Joining in Pandas Using Sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to join together two Pandas dataframes, partially using relative ordering.  The idea is to get the Letter # in the received table.

```
import pandas as pd

sntlist = [{'Link ID': 1, 'Sent date': '2020-01-01', 'Letter #': 1},
          {'Link ID': 1,  'Sent date': '2020-01-02',  'Letter #': 2}, 
          {'Link ID': 1,  'Sent date': '2020-01-03',  'Letter #': 3}, 
          {'Link ID': 1,  'Sent date': '2020-01-15',  'Letter #': 4}, 
          {'Link ID': 1,  'Sent date': '2020-01-20',  'Letter #': 5}, 
          {'Link ID': 2,  'Sent date': '2020-01-01',  'Letter #': 10}]
df_snt = pd.DataFrame(sntlist)
df_snt['Sent date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_snt['Sent date'])

reclist = [{'Link ID': 1,  'Receive Date': '2020-01-02'},
           {'Link ID': 1,  'Receive Date': '2020-01-04'}, 
           {'Link ID': 1,  'Receive Date': '2020-01-17'}, 
           {'Link ID': 1,  'Receive Date': '2020-01-18'}, 
           {'Link ID': 2,  'Receive Date': '2020-01-02'}]
df_rec = pd.DataFrame(reclist)
df_rec['Receive Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_rec['Receive Date'])
```

I'm trying to associate letter # from the sent table with the receive table.

What I can guarantee --

- Link ID will be the same between the two.
- Letters are always received after they are sent (and never on the same day)
- Letters will never arrive out of sequence.  (You will never receive letter 3 before receiving letter 2, but it's possible to receive letter 3, and never receive letter 2).
- All letters will arrive within a week of being sent.
- If multiple sent letters are candidates to be associated with a letter receipt, choose the one with the smallest difference between sent and received date.

What I can't guarantee --

- Not all letters sent show up in the received data, and vice versa.

It sounds like merge_ordered might help me here, but I'm not really familiar with it.

Expected output --

```
{'Letter #': 1, 'Receive Date': '2020-01-02,
'Letter #': 2, 'Receive Date':  None,
'Letter #': 3, 'Receive Date': '2020-01-04',
'Letter #': 4, 'Receive Date': '2020-01-17',
'Letter #': 5, 'Receive Date': None,
'Letter #': 10, 'Receive Date': '2020-01-02'}
```

Comment: kindly post ur expected output

Comment: I edited to add expected output.

Comment: y is letter 2 null even though it's received date is ahead of its sent date. i know it shares the same receive date with letter 3. is that another condition then, that no two letters can have the same receive date?

Comment: We don't know what the receive date of letter 2 or letter 3 actually is  -- remember, letters can get lost.  We do know that we received a letter on 2020-01-04, but we assigned it to letter 3, because the difference between 2020-01-03 and 2020-01-04 is smaller than the difference between 2020-01-02 and 2020-01-04.  Two letters can have the same receive date, but only if there were two letters received on that date, which isn't the case here.